# Mysql LEFT JOIN with IS NULL returning null result

Tags: mysql

I am trying to select row which is not in table.

In brief, there are five tables `student`, `cls`, `sec`, `sch`, `std_sch`. Here, I want to select rows from `std_sch` **which are not in** `sch`
But **LEFT JOIN** with **IS NULL** is returning null result.

Table `cls` - lists of Class

```
id  |   ttl
===========
1   |   One
2   |   Two
```

Table `sec` - lists of section

```
id  |   ttl
===========
1   |   A
2   |   B
```

Table `sch` - lists of scholarship

```
id  |   ttl
===============
1   |   First
2   |   Second
3   |   Third
```

Table `student`

```
id  |   ttl |   cls |   sec
===========================
1   |   John|   1   |   1
2   |   Paul|   1   |   0
```

Table `sdt_sch` - lists of scholarship assigned to student

```
id  |   s_id|   sdt_sch
=======================
1   |   1   |   1
```

Mysql Code

```
SELECT
    student.id AS sid, 
    student.ttl AS stdt, 
    cls.ttl AS cls,
    sec.ttl AS sec, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(sch.ttl) AS sch 
FROM 
    student
JOIN
    cls ON cls.id=student.cls 
LEFT JOIN
    sec ON sec.id=student.sec
LEFT JOIN
    std_sch ON std_sch.s_id = student.id
LEFT JOIN 
    sch ON sch.id = std_sch.sch_id
WHERE
    cls.id = 1
AND
    std_sch.sch_id IS NULL
GROUP BY
    student.id
```

**Expected Result** should be as follow : because First Scholarship (`sch - 1`) is exists in table `sdt_sch`. But I am getting null results about this row

```
sid |   stdt|   cls |   sec|    sch
============================================
1   |   John|   One |   A   |   Second,Third
2   |   Paul|   One |   A   |   First,Second,Third
```

**I have attached** - [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/24fd70/7) also

Comment: Check this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/24fd70/24
I have removed the where conditions - does this give u some hint !

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya, Main Point is I can't handle **where** condition. What you provide in your `sqlfiddle` is exactly reverse to my requirement. In your `sqlfiddle`, it is displaying the rows which has been **already assigned** to this student. But my expected result is to select rows **which are not assigned** to this student. It means which is not in `std_sch` **(student_scholarship)** table. In `std_sch` table only one row 1 is assigned to `student.id` 1, So in result It has to show every `sch.id` excepting 1 for this `student.id`.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya, so result should be `second,Third` for the student john, but it is showing `First` in `sqlfiddle` that you provided. Because `First` has been assigned already, So I need to escape `First` id and show rest of the rows.

Comment: Check if my below posted solution will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about below one

```
SELECT
  student.id AS sid, 
  student.ttl AS stdt, 
  cls.ttl AS cls,
  sec.ttl AS sec, 
  GROUP_CONCAT(sch.ttl) AS sch 
FROM 
  student
inner JOIN
  cls ON cls.id=student.cls 
LEFT JOIN
  sec ON sec.id=student.sec
left JOIN
  std_sch ON std_sch.s_id = student.id 
Left JOIN 
  sch ON sch.id != std_sch.sch_id or std_sch.sch_id is null
WHERE
  cls.id = 1
GROUP BY student.id;
```

Fiddle: [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/24fd70/30)

The idea is to find the scholar not assigned to a student, so doing a left join on sch will work

```
Left JOIN 
  sch ON sch.id != std_sch.sch_id or std_sch.sch_id is null
```

Comment: Great dude !! hadn't thought about this way, Thanks.